# How to filter a specific, non-constant float out of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I'm new to python and I've been trying to write a program to track the total value of my steam inventory. I've been able to retrieve all my skins and the prices, but the issue is isolating the price output from the steam_community_market.market module output, which is a list with a lot of unnecessary information. I haven't been able to find how to filter only specific strings from the lists. An example of the format of the list I'm trying to filter is:

```
skins_prices = [
    {'Mann Co. Supply Crate Key': {
        'success': True, 
        'lowest_price': '$2.50', 
        'volume': '6,489', 
        'median_price': '$2.45'},
     'AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)': {
        'success': True,
        'lowest_price': '$15.00',
        'volume': '749', 
        'median_price': '$14.78'}
    }
]
```

I haven't gotten to the part of adding the cost together, because first I need to isolate the "lowest price" for each item, how could I do that so I can use that number to calculate the total value/cost (meaning it needs to be a float)? Please tell me if you need more details or have any questions. Anything helps, thanks in advance.

Comment: Use nested loop. The outer loop iterates over the list elements, the inner loop loops over the dictionary items. Then you just add up `item['lowest_price']`. You'll need to remove the `$` first and convert to `float`.

Comment: can you add expected output in your question

Comment: The desired output for the solution is a list of floats that correspond to the "lowest price" for each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of nested dictionary as identified in the comment. Here's is a sample code to help out:

```
key = 'lowest_price'
lowest_prices = {}
for k, v in skins_prices[0].items():
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        if k1 == key:
            lowest_prices[k] = float(v1[1:])
print(lowest_prices)
```

output (I have removed the $ and converted to float):

```
{'Mann Co. Supply Crate Key': 2.5, 'AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)': 15.0}
```

Now you can use the new dictionary to manipulate the values. For example getting the sum total is done as below:

```
>> sum(list(lowest_prices.values()))
>> 17.5
```

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
low_prices = []

# as your list has only 1 component we are using `[0]` and iterating over it
for _, v in skins_prices[0].items():
    low_prices.append(float(v["lowest_price"][1:]))

print(low_prices)
```

Output:

```
[2.5, 15.0]
```

**explanation**

`v["lowest_price"][1:]` we are using indexing to ignore the first character from str which is `$` so now value will be `2.5` or `15`.

On this we are applying `float` to convert the `str` into `float` and appending it to new list which is `low_prices`

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. Can you explain what you did so I can understand and replicate it if needed in the future?

Comment: @HenruDorsey added explanation